# Because project requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed even though Dart SDK version is 2.14.0-350.0.dev

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I want to make use of typedefs for variables in Dart thus I am trying to update minimum dart version to 2.14.0.
When I change environment to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

I get the following error

```
[project] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in project...                      
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.0-377.0.dev.

Because project requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because project requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Now I am confused what `>=` means if my version is `2.14.something` and it does not satisfy condition `>=2.14.0`.
Any idea what's going on?

```
flutter doctor
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.5.0-5.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-GB)
...
```

Comment: your sdk is in dev mode try to update dark sdk to release one

Comment: Do you mean stable release? Currently the stable release is the 2.13.4 version if I look correctly.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I put -0 and now I can use typedefs for variables.  Thank you. You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Chris check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591005/4295614

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of the Dart SDK you have installed is `2.14.0-377.0.dev`; the `-377.0.dev` part indicates that it is a development release (a pre-release), which cannot satisfy a requirement for a stable version of 2.14.0 as required by your `pubspec.yaml` constraints.

(Imagine that a development release introduced some new feature before some major bug was noticed and fixed. If your package depends on that feature, you probably would not want an unstable development release to satisfy your package's dependency requirement by default.)

You can set `sdk: ">=2.14.0-0 <3.0.0"` instead (note the `-0`) to indicate that you accept development versions of 2.14.0.