# Requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter

The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

Because trackkit requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1

My pubspec.yaml :

```
    environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
```

after running flutter master:

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel master
Flutter 2.13.0-0.0.pre.145 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision de4eb16254 (3 hours ago) • 2022-03-18 06:00:24 -0400
Engine • revision edf31ab695
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-220.0.dev) • DevTools 2.11.4
```

It shows that my Dart is upgraded to 2.17.0 ? I am still unable to run!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. You need to upgrade your Dart SDK with:

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```
2. make sure to edit your environment in pubspec.yaml :

   ```
   environment:
     sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
   ```

Comment: manny reason can lead to this. My case was creating a project with master channel, an then change to stabel wich was a bit lower version.
I Basically needed to edit only my yaml (as pointed here), wich kept the new version.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This issue because of, you may installed multiple version of flutter in you system. And in android studio tools pointed to lower version of flutter location.

First you update flutter.

Then check flutter version.  `flutter --version` Make sure you are upgraded to your specified version.

Then check the location of the framework using  `which flutter`

Then you will get the path like */Applications/flutter/bin/flutter*

Then open android studio (in mac) go to `android studio preference`.

[image: android studio preference from menu]

Go to `Languages & Frameworks` from left menu.

Select `flutter` under the languages &framework section.

Add correct SDK path under `flutter SDK path` like - `/Applications/flutter`

If you add correct SDK path it will show the upgraded version and channel details below of the path.

Then click to `apply` and `ok`.

[image: Change language settings in android studio]

It will solve your issue.

Comment: This is really the right answer. I only meet this error when opening flutter project in android studio, but visual studio code. After having tried this answer, the error has gone away. Amazing!!!

Answer (score 1):

Update your SDK Version.To upgarde go to your android studio terminal and run following command.

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and cause seems to be like Arun suggested. New project was pointing to another, older flutter installation.

I solved my issue in VSCode by fixing the path in the Dart Extension settings, under SDK (in JSON). #5 is where my extension was pointing to another flutter installation:

[Dart Extension settings in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYIal.png)

[Path to Flutter SDK in Dart Extension settings JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Paa.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson